# run Nodejs module in phonegap

Tags: node.js, cordova, sencha-touch

Is it possible to run an an nodejs module inside an phonegap/dordavo or sencha touch on Android ?
I want to use an nodejs module to read my email through imap protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at http://browserify.org

It allows you to bundle up node modules to run client side (in the browser) - in your case, the PhoneGap/Cordova webview.